# How do we prevent a predominantly US focus?

Tags: discussion

I'm actually not convinced this is possible, given that the number of FAA-certified pilots probably approaches or exceeds the rest of the world.

I do think we should try. I'm not familiar with flying outside the US, but we seem to already have quite a few European pilots. Is it simply matter of them asking and answering questions to seed the topics, even if they're questions they already know the answer to? Or once the site reaches public beta will that become a moot point as more non-US pilots begin to participate?

Comment: I agree this could become an issue but I also think it's too early to say if it is and to know what to do about it. In the end the site will succeed if it's useful and it's not clear yet exactly how that will look, at least to me. But adding questions artificially is unlikely to help.

Comment: Would tagging solve this? If there were tags "Europe-Area", "US-Area" it would become clearer what special considerations have to be taken into account when answering.

Comment: We are also short on air traffic controllers and mechanics.  Everyone start inviting everybody that you work with!

Answer (score 3):

Probably by inviting more people who fly in non-US areas.  No?

Pardon the brief answer, but I can't see how it's more complicated than that - unless you're soliciting for how to reach out to non-US pilots.

Comment: That's reasonable, but at this point in time somewhat difficult. I don't know any non-US pilots, which is probably the case for most US pilots ( :) ), and I've only flown overseas once. So... yeah, I guess I'm asking how we reach out to non-US pilots and bring them into the beta phase.

Answer (score 2):

Approach some owner and pilot associations such as COPA (Canada), AOPA (UK), etc. in order to get some multinational interest.

If the questions seem to be coming with a primary focus on the United States, maybe some bounties on non-US questions could be set up?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing to do would be to include ICAO answers whenever possible.

Comment: Well, so far the questions have been pretty specific to the area that the asker cares about.  For instance, they usually ask "In the US, how do I...?" and we respond with answer specific to the FAA.  If someone asks about ICAO rules, then we should respond appropriately.  We just need more international questions (and probably international pilots to ask them)!