# Are questions on this site limited to the USA?

Tags: discussion

Are questions posted on aviation.stackexchange.com designed to be applicable to the U.S. only ... or are questions for other locales OK? If it's worldwide, perhaps there need to be some country tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happened here is that you're the first person to ask a question about Australia!

We don't just create tags - we only create one when a question requires it. And until you have enough rep, you can't create tags (you only need +8 more — [only 150 is required](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) while we're in beta).

As you rightfully asked [in your question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/2538/revisions), "can somebody with rep add this tag for me?", I've created it for you now.

Comment: Thanks - I sort of got the answer after I posted the question. My search on Australia and overseas didn't yield anything useful on meta. Hence my own answer to the question!

Answer (score 5):

After further research, the consensus seems to be that questions are *not* limited to the USA, however posters of questions should indicate the country (or regulatory body) that their questions apply to.

Related: [How do we prevent a predominantly US focus?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/how-do-we-prevent-a-predominantly-us-focus?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah - the real problem we have is most of the *users* are from the USA (so what we know of other countries is limited to what the folks we have around who do international flying know, or what we can Google up and figure out). We very much want a broader multi-national base, it's just taking a while to build up users in other regions :-)